Changing the number of tests to adjust for with add_q() from gtsummary package
I’m struggling to figure this out and it seems like there should be a way to do this, but I can't find a solution online.
Basically, I have three gtsummary tbl_cross() objects, and I am going to merge them so they are side by side. Each table is doing a fisher exact test, so it has a p-value and I want to add an adjusted p-value (q-value) to account for the multiple testing.
The problem is, gtsummary doesn’t allow you to add a q-value AFTER the tables are merged, but if I add the q-value to each table BEFORE they’re merged, it thinks I am adjusting for a single test, and the q-value = p-value.
I looked into the add_q() documentation and while there is an option to change the type of correction, there's no option to feed additional arguments into the method it is using to adjust. I see that when I use add_q() it prints out this message:
add_q: Adjusting p-values with
`stats::p.adjust(x$table_body$p.value, method = "holm")`

But I don't know how to get in there to add the 'n=3' argument you would add to p.adjust() in this case. Example below.
library(gtsummary)

toy_1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A","A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B"),
                    x2 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B"),
                    x3 = c("B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A"))

toy_2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("R","R", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "R", "G", "G"),
                    x2 = c("R", "G", "R", "R", "G", "R", "R", "G", "G", "G"),
                    x3 = c("G", "R", "R", "R", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"))

## Initiate empty list
list_out <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)

for (i in 1:3){
  ## Combine
  toy_combine <- data.frame(toy_1[,i], toy_2[,i])
  
  ## Rename
  colnames(toy_combine) <- c("toy_1", "toy_2")
  
  ## Create table
  tbl_toy <- tbl_cross(data = toy_combine,
                       row = toy_1, 
                       col = toy_2,
                       missing_text = "Missing") |>
    modify_header(label ~ "**toy_2**") |>
    bold_labels() |>
    add_p() |>
    add_q(method = "holm")
  
  ## Store in list
  list_out[[i]] <- tbl_toy
}

tbl_merge(tbls = list_out,
          tab_spanner = colnames(toy_1))

This results in the following table:
plot image
If I remove the add_q() from the individual tables and instead put:
tbl_merge(tbls = list_out,
          tab_spanner = colnames(toy_1)) |>
    add_q(method = "holm")

I get the following error:
Error: There is no p-value column. `x$table_body` must have a column called 'p.value'

Any help?

The add_q() function is meant to assist in the most basic cases. Merged tables can be quite complex and we wouldn't want to incorrectly perform the wrong calculation.
But you can simply add the adjusted p-values to the table with the code below, and specify that you are correcting for 3 tests. Example below
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")

toy_1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A","A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B"),
                    x2 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B"),
                    x3 = c("B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A"))

toy_2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("R","R", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "R", "G", "G"),
                    x2 = c("R", "G", "R", "R", "G", "R", "R", "G", "G", "G"),
                    x3 = c("G", "R", "R", "R", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"))

## Initiate empty list
list_out <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)

for (i in 1:3){
  ## Combine
  toy_combine <- data.frame(toy_1[,i], toy_2[,i])
  
  ## Rename
  colnames(toy_combine) <- c("toy_1", "toy_2")
  
  ## Create table
  tbl_toy <- tbl_cross(data = toy_combine,
                       row = toy_1, 
                       col = toy_2,
                       missing_text = "Missing") |>
    modify_header(label ~ "**toy_2**") |>
    bold_labels() |>
    add_p() |>
    modify_table_body(~.x |> dplyr::mutate(q.value = p.adjust(p.value, method = "holm", n = 3L))) |> 
    modify_header(q.value = "q-value") |> 
    modify_footnote(q.value = "Holm's Correction")
    
  
  ## Store in list
  list_out[[i]] <- tbl_toy
}

tbl_merge(tbls = list_out,
          tab_spanner = colnames(toy_1))


